# Can not connect to ENCRYPTED Access db (accdb) from VSTO (Excel Add-In) - but can from Console-App

Tags: c#, excel, ms-access, vsto, oledbconnection

From within an VSTO Excel Add-In I tried to connect to an **encrypted Access Database** (accdb) using OleDbConnection. (I tried on Excel 2010 and 2016 with different VSTO templates)

I get the **Error: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbErrorCollection: 'Not a valid password.'**
The Source of the Exception is: "Microsoft Access Database Engine".

The Exception does not contain any inner exception.

The **code runs without problems**:

- from within the Add-In if the targeted database is NOT encrypted.
- from a console app even if the accdb is encrypted.

So there is **no problem with the connection string, the path or the password**.

**What is different if the code is run in the context of an Add-In?**

I found that some people faced a similar problem (the same error message), when trying to connect to an encrypted accdb from ASP.NET and the permissions for the web process were not correct. Could this be a hint? IMHO the Add-In should run with user privileges, so this should not be the cause (and as described above, the connection to the database can be established, therefore the file opened, as long as the accdb is not encrypted)...

```cs
public void TestAccessConnect()
        {
            string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
                    @"Data Source=C:\temp\encryptedDb.accdb;" +
                    @"Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1234;";

            using (var oleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
            {
                oleDbConn.Open();  // <---- triggers the following error
                                    // Error: { System.Data.OleDb.OleDbErrorCollection} 
                                    // Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"
                                    // Message: "Not a valid password"
            }
        }
```

I did not find anything concerning my problem on the internet and I am running out of ideas. Is this a (known) bug on the MS side?

Any advice on where to look is highly appreciated.

---

***Update 2019/05/17:***

I found that if I encrypted the accdb in "legacy encryption", the connection works! :-(

To reproduce: 
In Access:

- Decrypt the database (DB must be opened exclusively)
- Go to File -> Options -> Client-Settings: There scroll to the "Advanced" section and tick "Legacy encryption" (instead of "Standard" - which is set by default)
- Close the database (might be optional)
- Reopen the database exclusively
- Encrypt the database.

Et voilà - now the database can be opened using the password from the Add-In.
Dear MS-guys - what the heck! The non working "default" encryption is there at since Office 2010 at least.

In addition: I did tried to connect directly to the accdb from Excel 365. Data -> Get Data.

- -> Database ->Access. Non encrypted (OK), Encrypted (Fail)
- -> Other Sources -> OLEDB: (here you can provide a connection string). Non encrypted (OK), Encrypted (Fail)
- -> Other Sources -> **ODBC**: (Set up a new ODBC-Connection, here you get to see some really cool dialog boxes from the last century): Non encrypted (OK), **Encrypted (OK)**

Well, it seems that one has to accept that Microsoft can't properly integrate their own database to their office suite. And hey, it's only been about 10 years than this is not working...

Just to make sure that it's not something Excel specific, I also created an Add-In for Word. Same experience.

So basically I can connect either by changing the encryption model (not very practical because there are many instances out there), or by using and ODBC-Connection (no good fit because I want to use EF Core - in this case for Access - (i know, i know, ... Access is about to be phased out)) or by just directly using ADODB or by remoting Access.

But, I still have the feeling that the .NET class SHOULD behave like a .NET class - even if it's hosted in an Office Application.

**Does anybody have an idea what could stop this simple command from working?**

---

***Update No2 2019/05/17:***

I put the connection code in a new DLL project. Then I have an Add-In project and a Console-Application. Both contain basically the same two lines of production code:

```
            var ac = new AccessConnectTest(); // <- class in own assembly
            ac.TestAccessLogin();
```

Console works. 
Add-In does not.

How is this possible? Does office fiddle with Assembly resolution?

Comment: Is Excel x64 bits? This sounds like a bit miss-match. the console app is likely x32, or x64 and the Excel app is the other perhaps?

Comment: Bitness is of course one of the typical culprits. But no. Add-In compiles to x86 and Office (Excel and Access) are only 32 bits. I forgot to mention that I had checked that.

Comment: Try the connection from a Word Add-in, as a test? The one thing that occurs to me about Excel VSTO projects is that they're *culture specific*. Maybe there's a connection to that - if so, it should work with Word...